# Apply switchery to all elements with given class

Tags: jquery

I am trying to apply switchery to all elements within my document with `classname="demo-sw"`.

I can apply it to one element by class name. like:

```
<input id="demo1" class="switchery switchery-primary" type="checkbox" data-switchery="true">
new Switchery(document.document.getElementById('demo1'), {color:'#489eed'});
```

How can i apply  it to all elements with classname `demo-sw`.

I tried:

```
$('.demo-sw').each(function(i, obj) {
    new Switchery($(this), {color:'#489eed'})
});
```

and

```
$('.demo-sw').each(function(i, obj) {
    new Switchery(i, {color:'#489eed'})
});
```

but it is not working.

Comment: From the [documentation](http://abpetkov.github.io/switchery/): `var elem = document.querySelector('.js-switch');
var init = new Switchery(elem);`

Comment: But `querySelector` selects only first matching element.

Comment: No it doesn't, it retrieves all elements matching the provided selector: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I just realised it.

Comment: No problem, glad to help. I added it as an answer for you.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan that should be `querySelectotAll()` not `querySelector()`

Comment: It worked .. Thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://abpetkov.github.io/switchery/), you can use `querySelectorAll` to provide a list of DOMElements to the plugin:

```
var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.demo-sw');
var init = new Switchery(elems, { color:'#489eed' });
```

If you'd prefer to use jQuery for this then you would need to loop through the selected elements individually and instantiate the plugin on them:

```
$('.demo-sw').each(function() {
    new Switchery(this, { color:'#489eed' })
});
```

Of these, the former is the better practice.

Answer (score 1):

### Try this out:- https://jsfiddle.net/adiioo7/313ube9h/

**JS:-**

```
var elems = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.js-switch'));

elems.forEach(function(html) {
  var switchery = new Switchery(html);
});
```

**HTML:-**

```
<input type="checkbox" class="js-switch" checked />

<input type="checkbox" class="js-switch" checked />

<input type="checkbox" class="js-switch" checked />
```

<kbd>[Reference](http://abpetkov.github.io/switchery/)</kbd>